# Blender Brush texture

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

i am learning the blender program following BlenderGuru videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nht2RoYBUfA
I was drawing the donut texture. When I use the brush I don't have a single stroke but fragmented or reproduced in other points.
Also I can't draw in the image editor panel, I can only use the annotate tool
Does anyone know how to do?
help me please

[image]

This is the uv editing
[image]
This is texture paint
[image]

---

This is one example
what can I do?
[image]

Comment: What does your UV map look like? Do you have overlapping islands/faces that might cause the paint to show up on two or more places at once? In the 2d paint, are you using the 2D Image Editor or trying to use the UV Editor with Grease Pencil to draw instead?

Comment: Ok, I just uploaded the images, the UV map has faces overlapped. I'm sorry but I don't know grease pencil, I tried to draw the donut in the texture paint panel. Overlapping faces I guess is a problem
  what can I do?

Comment: Since it is early in the painting process, you can solve the up issue by unwrapping using smart up projection which will get you anon overlapped up mapping. Then you should be able to continue with your tutorial.

Comment: Thank you mannnn <3 
it was easier than I expected
So is it normal for this to happen or did I do something wrong before?
in the tutorial he doesn't have this problem and has a square lattice

Comment: Probably the UV unwrap step wasn't clear or skipped altogether, but yes, a bad unwrap scheme will cause problems. Sometimes the easiest solution is to apply the scale of the object before unwrapping it, and that helps get a good result.